# Entity Framework schema always empty in EdmFunction when generating code using T4

Tags: entity-framework, t4

My goal was to use Entity Framework stored procedures and functions in an `async` way, but the built-in support isn't there. The default T4 code only generates sync methods.

After a lot of searching and trial and error I settled with modifying my `Model.Context.tt` to generate appropriate code by calling `ExecuteStoreCommandAsync` and/or `ExecuteStoreQueryAsync`.

Unlike `ExecuteFunction` which simply wants the function name regardless of schema, `ExecuteStoreCommandAsync` also needs schema prefixed to the procedure name (e.g. `[MySchema].[MyProcedure]`).

The class [`EdmFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.edmfunction?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) apparently has a [`Schema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.edmfunction.schema?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) property but it's empty for all my functions. If I open `EDMX` as text I can clearly see something like:

```
<Function Name="MyProcedure" Schema="MySchema">
```

The question is - how can I access the correct schema in TT for my stored procedure/function?

I am using EF 6.2 in a NET Framework 4.7 project.

Comment: I ended up adding code to T4 that reads EDMX directly and parses XML for `Schema`. Not too pretty but it isn't that bad either. It's getting the job done.

Comment: I was the same problem and i implements exactly this solution :), Do you already think that it is the single solution? so complex and annoying :( If yes - do you want to provide more code?

Answer (score 3):

EF6 metadata system is quite complicated, probably due to the attempt to cover too many scenarios - database first, code first and model first. They have separate metadata organized in so called *dataspaces* - store model, object model and conceptual model plus mappings between them.

The problem here is that the standard EF6 T4 generator uses the conceptual model. It's because `ExecuteFunction` and `CreateQuery` work with `EntityCommand`s (Entity SQL) which later are transformed to "store" commands (raw SQL). While `ExecuteStoreCommand[Async]` and `ExecuteStoreQuery[Async]` work directly with "store" commands (raw SQL).

So what you need is an access to the "store" model. Note that both "conceptual" and "store" models contain `EdmFunction` objects, but their names are different, so are the parameter names, types etc. And since `Schema` makes sense only for "store" (database), that's why you are getting always `null` from the conceptual model.

Here is how you can load and get `EdmFunction`s from the store mode. The standard EF6 T4 template includes a file called `EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude` which contains many helpers used by code generation. One of them is a class called `EdmMetadataLoader` with method `CreateEdmItemCollection` used by the standard template for loading the conceptual model from EDMX. It can be used as base to extract a method that we need, which looks like this (add it at the end of the modified Context.tt inside the section of code helpers - before the last closing `#>`):

```
private static StoreItemCollection CreateStoreItemCollection(string sourcePath, IDynamicHost host, System.Collections.IList errors)
{
    var root = XElement.Load(host.ResolvePath(sourcePath), LoadOptions.SetBaseUri | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    var schemaElement = root.Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Runtime")
        .Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "StorageModels")
        .Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Schema")
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? root;
    if (schemaElement != null)
    {
        using (var reader = schemaElement.CreateReader())
        {
            IList<EdmSchemaError> schemaErrors;
            var itemCollection = StoreItemCollection.Create(new[] { reader }, null, null, out schemaErrors);
            foreach (var error in schemaErrors)
            {
                errors.Add(
                    new CompilerError(
                        error.SchemaLocation ?? sourcePath,
                        error.Line,
                        error.Column,
                        error.ErrorCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        error.Message)
                    {
                        IsWarning = error.Severity == EdmSchemaErrorSeverity.Warning
                    });
            }
            return itemCollection ?? new StoreItemCollection();
        }
    }
    return new StoreItemCollection();   
}
```

Then find the line

```
var itemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
```

and insert the following line after it

```
var storeItemCollection = CreateStoreItemCollection(inputFile, textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors);
```

Now you can replace the standard

```
foreach (var edmFunction in container.FunctionImports)
{
    WriteFunctionImport(typeMapper, codeStringGenerator, edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption: false);
}
```

with

```
var functions = storeItemCollection
    .GetItems<EdmFunction>()
    .Where(f => !f.IsFromProviderManifest)
    .ToList();
foreach (var edmFunction in functions)
{
#>
    // [<#=edmFunction.Schema ?? ""#>].[<#=edmFunction.Name#>]
<#
}
```

The body just outputs a comment with [Schema].[Name] of each db function import to prove the correct `edmFunction.Schema` property (the target of the question). Replace it with the actual code generation.

---

In case you need both conceptual (code) and storage (db) definitions of a function, you can create `StorageMappingItemCollection` in a similar fashion (the only difference is that it requires passing `EdmItemCollection` and `StoreItemCollection` that you already have in addition to the xml reader), e.g. (`CreateStorageMappingItemCollection` is the method you have to create and implement):

```
var storageMappingItemCollection = CreateStorageMappingItemCollection(
    (EdmItemCollection)itemCollection, storeItemCollection,
    inputFile, textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors);
```

and then use

```
var functionImports = storageMappingItemCollection
    .GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>()
    .SelectMany(m => m.FunctionImportMappings)
    .ToList();
```

to get a list of [FunctionImportMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.mapping.functionimportmapping?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) objects having two `EdmFunction` type properties: [FunctionImport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.mapping.functionimportmapping.functionimport?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Core_Mapping_FunctionImportMapping_FunctionImport) (conceptual model) and [TargetFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.mapping.functionimportmapping.targetfunction?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Core_Mapping_FunctionImportMapping_TargetFunction) (storage model).

**Update** You really need to use the aforementioned "mapping" approach. `FunctionImport` provides the necessary information for defining the C# method (name, arguments, return type) while `TargetFunction` provides the information needed to call the db function/procedure.

So the helper method looks like this:

```
private static StorageMappingItemCollection CreateStorageMappingItemCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection, string sourcePath, IDynamicHost host, System.Collections.IList errors)
{
    var root = XElement.Load(host.ResolvePath(sourcePath), LoadOptions.SetBaseUri | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    var schemaElement = root.Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Runtime")
        .Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Mappings")
        .Elements()
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Mapping")
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? root;
    if (schemaElement != null)
    {
        using (var reader = schemaElement.CreateReader())
        {
            IList<EdmSchemaError> schemaErrors;
            var itemCollection = StorageMappingItemCollection.Create(edmItemCollection, storeItemCollection, new[] { reader }, null, out schemaErrors);
            foreach (var error in schemaErrors)
            {
                errors.Add(
                    new CompilerError(
                        error.SchemaLocation ?? sourcePath,
                        error.Line,
                        error.Column,
                        error.ErrorCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        error.Message)
                    {
                        IsWarning = error.Severity == EdmSchemaErrorSeverity.Warning
                    });
            }
            if (itemCollection != null) return itemCollection;
        }
    }
    return new StorageMappingItemCollection(edmItemCollection, storeItemCollection);    
}
```

and the sample usage:

```
var storageMappingItemCollection = CreateStorageMappingItemCollection(
    (EdmItemCollection)itemCollection, storeItemCollection,
    inputFile, textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors);

var functionImports = storageMappingItemCollection
    .GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>()
    .SelectMany(m => m.FunctionImportMappings)
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in functionImports)
{
#>
    // <#=item.FunctionImport.Name#> => [<#=item.TargetFunction.Schema ?? ""#>].[<#=item.TargetFunction.Name#>]
<#
}
```

Comment: Now i pay attention that the edmFunction return type also is null, In the method  FunctionMethod i use the follow line var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction); and always accept null, Any solution?

Comment: That info seems to be coming from the "other" `EdmFunction` definition. Looks like you really need to use the "mapping" approach mentioned at the end of the answer, and get the necessary info from the object containing it.

Comment: @StackOverflow Looks like "mapping" is the way to go - answer updated.

Comment: After rereading your first answer i understood  my problem ,But your detailed code help me very much, Thanks again!